# How to configure Google App Engine health checking endpoints for managed VMs

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine requests /_ah/health from the managed vm to do health checking.

I trying to deploy a project that I'm not the code maintainer, it's going to be deployed as managed vm to have autoscaling and health checking.

Currently app.yaml doesn't support rewrite rules, if it supported I could point the /_ah/health to a /ping endpoint. This would be great because health checking could be implemented without changing code.

In app.yaml there is the configuration for handlers, my understanding is that handler are for use with the google runtime, not for managed VMs.

I want to change the location of the /_ah/health request. Is there a way to do this change?

Comment: You can customize a lot of the health check parameters, per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/#health_checking , but not, AFAIK, the URL it uses.  Can't you just serve health checks at that URL as well as any other?  What specialized task are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: The use case is to support the deployment of apps without changing the source code.

Comment: And if health checks went to say `/health/mine` rather than `/_ah/health` how would that facilitate your task?  You can use `app.yaml` (or equivalent mechanisms in Java) to switch what part of your code serves health checks, whichever of the two URLs you're using.

Comment: I could point the health check request to an already existing endpoint in the app (that responded to a get with 200) without changing code. I've searched the documentation and couldn't found a way to configure app.yaml to rewrite request, like apache does.

Comment: Why do you need to **rewrite** the request?  Can't you just point it, as is, to that existing endpoint?  I'd recommend editing your Q to provide a clear detailed explanation of what you're aiming for and why you can't use the obvious approach, as this comment thread is getting too long and the Q stays too short:-).

Comment: @AlexMartelli I think that's what he's asking. I have this same issue, I have an app which responds to `/ping`, not `/_ah/health`, and I would like to deploy the app without code changes. From the documentation, I see no way to adjust `app.yaml` to change the URL google uses for health checking.

Comment: I guess I must be missing something about the problem, since the "code changes" (to the routing parts of your code), if even needed, are so miniscule.  I guess you can open a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list , but given how trivially easy is the workaround, I can't imagine it being prioritized highly.  Anyway, just to make sure we're communicating clearly, let me post an answer to show what I would do in your shoes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, suppose you have a "health-check serving endpoint" (using `webapp2` for definiteness, other frameworks would of course work similarly) in `health.py`:

```
class HealthPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.write('<html><body><p>I\'m fine!</p></body></html>')
```

and unfortunately you also have routing information hard-coded, say in the same file (rather than more properly reading it from an easily modified and pushed configuration file):

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/howareyou', HealthPage),
])
```

Now, to serve health checks from that same `HealthPage` handler, you need to edit your `app.yaml` to have:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/health
  script: health.application
```

**before** any handlers whose `url:` has wildcards that might "swallow" this one, of course.

Now, since you have a strict, hard-coded routing decision in your application object, you'll have to edit that.  This isn't really "editing code" -- it's editing configuration information that you unfortunately decided to embed as strict, hard-coded strings in your code, rather than picking it up from a configuration code.

Either make the in-code routing less strict, maybe all the way down to:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('.*', HealthPage),
])
```

or if you're committed to using very strict hardcoded routes in your code, you' might choose to add one line...:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/howareyou', HealthPage),
  ('/_ah/health', HealthPage),
])
```

Similarly for other routing systems (beyond `app.yaml` and other configuration-based routing done for you by App Engine itself) of course -- `webapp2`'s routing system is nothing strange, nor anomalous.

Note that none of these edits stop your code from serving the `/howareyou` URL if it's routed to `health.py` in other (non-GAE and non-GAE-like) deployments -- they'll serve it just as well as they used to do.

If despite all of this you still demand a "URL rewriting" capability in `app.yaml`, or similarly powerful features, to deal with health checks while avoiding the need for this kind of tiny workaround, you can of course open a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list -- I just can't imagine it getting high urgency vs the thousands of open issues there, but, hey!, I've been wrong before:-).

Comment: I've opened an issue for this feature at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11636

Comment: This is an old issue, but has anyone been able to resolve this for rails?