# Specify Google App Engine health check endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How do I specify a health check endpoint in my GAE health_check entry in app.yaml? I see options for various thresholds but I have no indication of how to set a custom endpoint or even if my options are being respected.

The app engine documentation states that `/_ah/health` is used for health checks but I would like to provide my own health checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can still write your own custom health-checking code. It just needs to reply to /_ah/health request with HTTP 200.

Comment: I did that but the underlying container image seems to return 'OK'. I am extending `FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/base`

Comment: Maybe information here would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819610/how-to-configure-google-app-engine-health-checking-endpoints-for-managed-vms/28226307

Comment: Yikes. That's not a very clean solution. A simple redirect/rewrite is all I really want. At any rate, how would someone accomplish this in a non-python language/runtime? Besides, the docs indicate that this is depricated. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/wsgiapplicationclass